# Can the order of initialization of the configuration classes in @ContextConfiguration be influenced?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to manage configurations in my application. The configurations are created so that they provide only the beans that are exposed by that given module. For this reason, some beans that are used by the given module are not necessarily imported directly. Example:

```
configuration --(use)--> module1 --(cannot @Import)--> database
              \-(use)--------------------------------> database
```

In words, the `configuration` uses `module1` which requires (but **must not directly import**) the database configuration. Therefore, `configuration` uses the `database` module as well.

But it seems like the order in which the imports are resolved is quite random. Even if I use

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={DatabaseConfig.class, Module1Config.class})
```

This results in indeterministic failure on initialization (`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`).

Is there any way to influence the order in which the beans are initialized? Or should I create an overlay of configurations that `@Import` the configurations along the dependencies? But in that case the same question applies to `@Import` as it has to ensure the order in which the dependencies are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to have stemmed from the different versions of spring being available at the same time. When the code was left to run, only a fraction of the `@Imports` were loaded by the `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(‌​AnnotationMetadata, Set<Object>, Set<Object>)` method. When the execution was suspended by a breakpoint during the parsing, everything worked completely fine.

As soon as the *multiple versions of the spring libs were cleaned up*, the issue went away. (At least it has not appeared again after a dozen or so runs.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [@DependsOn](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) annotation - it designed exactly for such cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, the @DependsOn annotation just makes the dependency explicit but does not cause backtracking to possibly load the missing beans from other configurations.

Comment: What real problem you try to solve and why your dependent beans should not be described as dependent in configuration (may be via interfaces)?

Comment: If I include the DB configuration in the configuration of the modules that use it, then it will be impossible to change that DB definition to something else. For example, if I want to focus my unit tests on a higher level module, I try to avoid loading the DB and try to break the dependency tree as soon as possible. Either I create different configurations for the testing and production or I create the configurations in a focused way and avoid import dependencies between them, this way in tests I can select what I load.

Comment: And how you then use DB in module that need DB for production, but not injected by spring? with context.getBean(...) ?

Comment: I boiled down the issue to some weird timing glitch. I have no clue how it happens but `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(AnnotationMetadata, Set<Object>, Set<Object>)` some times does not load all imported classes. If the process is delayed anywhere with a breakpoint, then everything works perfectly. This is serious shit and I have no clue how I could debug it. It's a Heisen bug, when I look at it, it disappears. Thanks a lot for trying. I give you a reps for it.